# Rails Server Startup Error mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've been working on a project the last few days, and I've been struggling with an error when starting up my rails server with the 'rails server' command. I have searched the whole internet for an answer but I dont really seem to find a solution to my problem.

The problem is that when I launch rails server with the command I get this output:

[image]

Output as seen on image.

Comment: It seems you don't have installed Redis server.

Comment: Did you install Redis in your machine?

Comment: I installed Redis and it finally worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to install Redis.

There is a Gem for that and you can see the installation instructions [HERE](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb)